# In court can you ask someone for all names they go by? How would question be phrased?

Tags: identification, rules-of-evidence

In a hearing the plaintiff has reason to believe that the defendant may have some type of pseudonym or sometimes use a variations of his name (like going by his middle name and leaving out the first).

What questions can the plaintiff put to the defendant to find the full enumeration of all of his names? I don't even know what some types of names are called, like "Catholic Confirmation Name".

Must the defendant answer, or could a judge decide if this is relevant? It could make a difference to evidence, for example if a letter was directed to "Joe Blow" but the defendants legal name is "Jim Joe" but they are one in the same person.

Comment: Any particular jurisdiction?

Comment: Keep it simple and just ask the question. "What are all the names you are known by?" Then follow up with "Is that all, or are there any more?" If it's relevant to the case then the judge should allow it. Failure (or compulsion) to answer depends on the jurisdiction

Comment: @Studoku Canada, British Columbia

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a perfectly common question. "What is your full name?" "Do you have any aliases?" "What other names do you go by?"

Like any other question, though, it must be relevant, and you should be prepared to explain why it is relevant. If the court allows the question, the defendant must answer.

Comment: Also: have you ever used the name XY?  Or: What is your relation to XY?

Comment: Just to be clear, should I ask if he has any "pseudonyms"?

Comment: That's another good way to ask.